# Getting error while loading data to RDS from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to load data from s3 to amazon RDS database, below is the code I am using to load data:

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-s3 ^
--allocated-storage 250 ^ 
--db-instance-identifier myidentifier ^
--db-instance-class db.m4.large ^
--engine mysql ^
--master-user-name masterawsuser ^
--master-user-password masteruserpassword ^
--s3-bucket-name mybucket ^
--s3-ingestion-role-arn arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/rolename ^
--s3-prefix bucketprefix ^
--source-engine mysql ^
--source-engine-version 5.6.27
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
An error occurred (DBInstanceAlreadyExists) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromS3 operation: DB Instance already exists
```

How to resolve to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The error message suggests that when you restore, you need to restore to a *new* RDS DB instance (one that does not already exist).

Comment: @jarmod, I created this DB instance specifically for restoring the data from s3. So, It would always exists while restoring.